# Увеличить время для hover`a

Tags: html, css

Есть код, как увеличить время возврата в первоначальное положение, т.е. оно доходит до половины  и спустя допустим 30 секунд или 1 час возвращается обратно

```css
button {
    height: 42px;
 border: none;
 background: #3a7999;
 color: #f2f2f2;
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 18px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 position: relative;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 transition: all 500ms ease; 
}

button:before {
 content:'';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 0;
 height: 42px;
 background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 border-radius: 5px;
 transition: all 2s ease;
}

button:hover:before {
 width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<button>Сюда иди</button>
```

Comment: А вы в состояние hover:before пробовали менять задержку?

Comment: То есть транзишн именно для состояния, то есть если вам надо быструю анимацию на ховер, то там и указывайте, если надо долгую анимацию без ховер то аналогично там и меняйте

Comment: Т.е. в botton:hover:before нужно указать транзишн? Я просто только изучаю верстку,многого не понимаю

Comment: https://codepen.io/walfter/pen/ExYKRPe вот если я вас правильно понял

Comment: Да,все верно,спасибо вам!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```css
button {
    height: 42px;
 border: none;
 background: #3a7999;
 color: #f2f2f2;
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 18px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 position: relative;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 transition: all 500ms ease; 
}

button:before {
 content:'';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 0;
 height: 42px;
 background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 border-radius: 5px;
 transition: all 30s ease;
}

button:hover:before {
 width: 50px;
    transition: all 2s ease;
}
```

```html
<button>Сюда иди</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для указания задержки перед выполнением анимации, надо указывать 4 параметр в transition.